# AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'CloseError'

Tags: python, dns, network-programming, dnspython

```
import dns 
import dns.resolver
result = dns.resolver.query('tutorialspoint.com', 'A')
for ipval in result:
    print('IP', ipval.to_text())
```

This is my code, and i am getting an error in 'httpcore' as,
AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'CloseError'
i will be greatful if anyone will help me in this.

i had tried to reinstall the package of dnspython that is now called as dns in python, but still the same error persisting... if anyone could help in this i will be thankful.

Comment: What python version you are using?

Comment: Python Version 3.11.4

Comment: Can you create a venv and install dnspython in it, and check if error persists?